# xamarin forms error converting values "[json]" to list

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin to build cross-platform mobile applications.
To Fetch data from SQL server I have created a web API and hosted it in my LAN network.
I have tested it and it works perfectly as expected.

**Edit-Added Json**
Json is

```
[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"D","LastName":"M","Company":"MD"},{"Id":2,"FirstName":"D","LastName":"S","Company":"DM"},{"Id":6,"FirstName":"MD","LastName":"","Company":"MD"},{"Id":8,"FirstName":"DM","LastName":"D","Company":""}]
```

In `xamarin.forms` I have a list, where I would deserialize the JSON and assign it as ItemsSource.

The Problem is no matter what way I try to deserialize the JSON, it throws an error in Conversion.

**Edit**
I used DataContract attribute only while trying to deserialize with DataContractJsonSerializer.

Here is my PO class for JSON,

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

Here are some codes which used to deserialize JSON,

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Url);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var Employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(content);
    empListView.ItemsSource = Employees;
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Failed", "Connection Failed", "OK");
}
```

It resulted in a error

[image: Error Image]

To fix this, i modified the above code as,

```
List<Employee> Employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(content);
```

It resulted in same error, i tried using array,

```
Employee[] Employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee[]>(content);
```

In another discussion regarding the same issue in this stack overflow I found a code and tried that too,

```
using (var web = new WebClient())
{
    var response = web.DownloadString(Url);
    Employee[] emp;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response)))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Employee[]));
        emp = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Employee[];
    }
    empListView.ItemsSource = emp;
}
```

but it too didn't help.
Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: You might wanna add the response json here which could make it easier to find the issue

Comment: @FreakyAli Sorry bro, Forgot to Add it. Now i have added it.

Comment: In the bunch of above types which i tried to deserialize, there would be one where i would use DataContractJsonSerializer. For it, I need to use DataContract. I used DataContract only during DataContractJsonSerializer. while trying with JsonConvert i didn't used it. Eventhough i didn't used it, it reflected the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the JSON-string from the response, my guess is that you serialize the object to JSON before returning it, the API should serialize objects to JSON by default. Try to just return the object from the API.

Comment: Tq. Exactly, That's what i did. serialized data as json string and returned it. Now, i retured the resulting data as objects without serializing them. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
List<Employee> Employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(content);
```

Try:

```
List<Employee> Employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(content.ToString());
```

Hope it helps. Let me know!

Comment: tried it. but still results in the same conversion error

Comment: `content` comes from `var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` which returns an string. This means that `content` is already of type `string` so no need to do the casting.